# How to enable Multiple buffer channel in HornetQ

Tags: netty, hornetq

I am working on a app which has a lot of asynchronous messages hosted by HornetQ 2.3.21. By some process my message size goes more than 2GB and the message starts failing with this message on the server:

```
HQ212017: error adding packet: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Maximum size of 2gb exceeded
   at org.jboss.netty.buffer.DynamicChannelBuffer.ensureWritableBytes(DynamicChannelBuffer.java:82) [netty-3.6.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.9.Final-redhat-1]
```

I want to enable multiple buffer channel for the app. Can someone please help me out with a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to enable "multiple buffer channel" in HornetQ. This looks like a bug in HornetQ. The HornetQ code-base is no longer maintained since its [donation to the Apache ActiveMQ community](https://planet.jboss.org/post/hornetq_apache_donation_and_apache_artemis_1_0_0_release) 6 years ago. HornetQ is still open-source so you're free to fix any bugs you find and build your own release(s), but I recommend you move to [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) which is based on the donated HornetQ code-base.

Comment: Unlikely we cannot move to ActiveMQ Artemis at this point of time but would need to find a solution in HornetQ itself. Do you know any way to set max message size or we can set a size after which it does pagination?

Comment: What do you mean by "after which it does pagination"? You could potentially create a "incoming" [remoting interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/intercepting-operations.html) to check the size of the message and reject it if it's larger than you want.